# Using the twitter API for background processing

Tags: api, twitter, oauth

'Background processing' is a terrible term, but I can't think of a better one at this time on a Friday!

I need a specific part of my web app to communicate with twitter - post a status using a single, fixed account. Every twitter oauth tutorial I've seen talks about applications in the general sense - those with multiple users. Does anyone have an example of basic twitter status updating via a non-interactive process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, after a lot of searching and hair-pulling, the answer seems to be:

1. Go to your app settings page on twitter
2. Click the 'My Access Token' button in the right hand column
3. Take a note of the sccess token details on this page
4. Follow [these instructions](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_single_token) to use the single-use token details